# Which style exists for mocking with Rhino?

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks, arrange-act-assert

I heard that latest style is AAA. Is there any other one? Why we use one and don't use another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are 2 major styles - one is the classic one (not sure what is the name) - which existed from the beginning and the earliest versions of .Net (certainly I used it with .Net 1.1) and the AAA one. Both are still fully functional, so feel free to use any (but you can't mix them - it simply doesn't work and you will get weird errors).

The AAA style was developed after lambda expressions and extension methods were introduced in C# and many people (including me) think it is cleaner, easier to read and expresses the intent of the test better.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the new AAA style and the old record/replay style is best understood by examining the difference between mocks and stubs. AAA uses stubs, while record/replay uses mocks.

I have blogged about the difference [here](http://mindinthewater.blogspot.com/2010/02/mocking-frameworks-stubs-vs-mocks.html).